# 2D numpy.ndarray comparing column elements to 2 neighboring elements in a row speed up?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, astropy

From astropy I get 2D numpy.ndarray shape of data: (2016, 3040)
It is a 6Mpx Array
I want to search for defects in the 3040 columns.

My definition for a column error is when
500 times in column n
value of "cell" (m,n) is 50 units smaller than the cell m,n-2 AND m,n+2 with m 0.... 2016
I count the occurence in result_array when iterating over the rows m

It works,erors are identified correctly- but it is slow.
As I want to process 20-40 images and later correct the column defect. So time is an issue.

Before this brute force approach I was experimenting with the column.mean() function.
This was not suitable to detect bad columns.
Still I do not check if the defect occurs from m,m+1, m+2 ... consecutively.
Just counting and assuming that a column error is when appr. 25% of the pixels in one column show sigificantly lower values (here 50) than the neighboring pixels.

There is a tool named fixfits , created by Sander Pool. This tool, by Sander Pool is not available anymore. I fear sander Pool has passed away.
With the coming version of Windows you never know if it will work on future versions.

Some ideas how to speed up the processinge.g. with numpy are highly appreciated.

This is the data structure

classification of data: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
shape of data: (2016, 3040)
one row as example: [   0 1446 1402 ... 1347 1421    0]
shape of row: (3040,)

Here my Python code

```
import numpy as np
row_index =0
col_index =0
row_max = 2016
col_max = 3040
threshold_intensity = 50
result_array= np.zeros(col_max)

for x in range(2,col_max-2):
    for y in range( 1, row_max-1):
        compare =  data[y,x] + 50 #threshold_intensity
        if ((compare < data[y,x-2]) and (compare < data[y,x+2])):
            result_array[x] = result_array[x]+1
            if result_array[x] >500 :
                print("Index: "+ str(x))
                break

            
for i in range(1,500):
    print (str(i)+"  :" + str(result_array[i]))
```

Studying astroy, numpy ans Python forums

Comment: What are you trying to actually do on a higher level? It sounds like maybe you're trying to detect bad columns in a CCD image. There are existing tools for things like that--ccdproc for example might be of help--but it would help to have an example of the kind of data you're working with and what your analysis goals are, so nobody leads you astray with examples that are irrelevant to you. Your code is slow because you're not using numpy correctly. In short, you should not be writing any explicit for loops to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Here's a tutorial I give beginners to numpy--hopefully it can help you understand how to use vectorized operations properly. https://github.com/embray/notebooks/blob/master/numpy.ipynb

Comment: I search for numpy procedures to compare a column(n) vector  to the 2 neighboring columns (n-2, n+2) component by component. II need to know how often column n is darker than the neighbors. In excess of 25% of the pixels in a column there is a column defect. Next step pixel value in n is replaced by the average value of the neigbor in the row. It is some cheating.
I did not find a procedure in numpy.
As I am novice to stackoverflow can I upload a datafile with 12 MB ?

Comment: I want to avoid the loops. In the numpy docs I did not find a procedure /set of them  to compare vectors to vectors component by component. This is why I am asking to experienced users of numpy. ccdproc regretfully does not check for defects nor remove them. It is quite sophisticated and science oriented so no room for tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

If your only goal is to eliminate the loops, I think you can do something like this

```py
compare = data + threshold_intensity
mask = (compare < np.roll(data, -2, axis=-1) & (compare < np.roll(data, 2, axis=-1)
result_array = mask.sum(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

#testing operation with real image array
 ​

source =data               # ndarray from fits-file
source_offset = source +50 # add permitted tolerance, keep original data

compare_right=np.roll(source, -2, axis=1)  # shift 2cols left
compare_left=np.roll(source, 2, axis=1)    # shift 2cols right

averageArray = compare_right + compare_left # building averaged values for later correction
averageArray= averageArray//2 # integer division sufficiently accurate for later use

comresright = source_offset < compare_right # reduce to boolean values
comresleft  = source_offset < compare_left 
comresleft  = comresleft & comresright # True only if TRUE in both compare array 

count= np.count_nonzero(comresleft, axis =0)# number of "TRUEs" per column

count[count<=500]=0 # set to 0 if 500 TRUEs or less -> col is o.k.
count[count>0]=1 # set to 1 for adding to an accumulator for summary overview

print(count.shape)
print ('\nindices where elements are = 1:')
indexes = np.where(count>0)[0]
print (indexes)                             # indexes contains integers only
```

Output is
(3040,) which is the width of the array.

indices where elements are == 1:
[   0  184  451 3039]

This is much faster than the loops.
1st column and last column will be discarded for correction. The indicated columns a truly defects in the CCD sensor. The identification works. Now it goes for the batch operation. Parsing all images in a directory and do the correction (here in col 184 and 451). The columns will be replaced by the corresponding columns in averageArray.

​